# How To inflate a Fragments inside a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to inflate a fragment called `MoviesFragment` into a container with id

```
R.id.container.



getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.panel_one_id, new MoviesFragment());
```

I see no result appears here 
Can I know where is my problem?

Comment: You forgot to call `commit()` on the `FragmentTransaction`, after `replace(...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time

Answer (score 2):

First add the fragment then replace it.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.panel_one_id, new MoviesFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every fragment transaction you do (add/replace/remove) you have to `commit` it to take effect. So the correct code will be:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.panel_one_id, new MoviesFragment()).commit();
```